# On the set of vectors obtained by a linear combination with bounded coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I have a squared matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ with full rank.

I am considering the set
$$
V = \{ v = Ma: \text{for }a\in \mathbb{R}^{k}, ||a||_2 \leq 1\}
$$

I can say that $V\subset W$, where
$$
W = \{v\in  \mathbb{R}^{k}: ||v||_2\leq ||M||_F \}
$$
where $||M||_F$ is the Frobenious norm of $M$, by the fact that
$$
||v||_2 = ||Ma||_2\leq ||M||_F
$$

Can I also say that  $V\supset W$, and so that $W=V$?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that $V \supset W$ , because $0 \in W$, while $0 \notin V$, because $M$ has full rank.

Comment: RIght. I have edited the definition of $V$ asking for $||a||_2 \leq 1$, that should cover your case and be more general